# C++ on mac OSX using Xcode , Clearing command monitor, and Stepping forward without Enter

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I've finished programming the Game of Life for c++.
I'm trying to make that with pushing a key, it clears the console and it draws the new generation, until we press for example "x". If you don't know about game of life, my main problem is to make a loop which clears the screen and execute functions without pushing  enter !
Yet I'm using this, but this needs enter to execute , and does not clears the screen. I get a massage saying "TERM environment variable not set.":

```
 while( x!= 'x')
{
    system("clear");
    m1.UPDATE();
    getchar();
    cout << " press " << endl;
    x = cin.get();
}
```

Thanks for your time and help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [ncurses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ncurses.3x.html)? It's included with the development environment provided by Apple. It's a framework for terminal handling and will do everything you would want. This includes being able to clear the screen ([`clear(3x)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/curs_clear.3x.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/curs_clear)) and reading keyboard input without displaying the characters([`noecho(3x)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/curs_inopts.3x.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/curs_inopts)) or waiting for `enter` ([`cbreak(3x)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/curs_inopts.3x.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/curs_inopts)).

Comment: I haven't heard about that until now. I will try it! Thanks for your help